# ORA-00905: missing keyword in where case statement

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

```
select m_seqe
      ,m_emai
      ,m_phon
      ,e_seqe
      ,m_id
      ,
      ( case 
        when (:M_STAT = 0 )  and (m_id is not null ) then 'a'
        when (:M_STAT = 0 )  and (m_id is null  ) then 'b'
        when (:M_STAT = 200 ) then 'c'
        Else ' - ' end ) as Stat
from m_users 
where m_stat = :M_STAT   
and  m_id =
case when (:M_ID = 0 ) then m_id is null
     when (:M_ID ='a') then m_id is not null
else 'do nothing' end
```

Comment: try to replace end with end case

Comment: Why do you have `:` , is this really part of your param names or? Also, double check your last case statements, specifically these `WHEN ( :M_ID = 0 ) THEN m_id IS NULL`...

Comment: why i have : in part of column name becauser I took the variables and compared them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you put it & I understood what you're saying, that would be a combination of several `OR` conditions:

```
 WHERE   m_stat = :M_STAT
   AND (   ( m_id IS NULL     AND :m_id = 0)
        OR ( m_id IS NOT NULL AND :m_id = 'a')
        OR ( m_id = 'do nothing'
       );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a case expression to determine the logic in a filter; so this doesn't make sense and is what the parser is complaining about:

```
and  m_id =
case when (:M_ID = 0 ) then m_id is null
     when (:M_ID ='a') then m_id is not null
else 'do nothing' end
```

You could potentially have a case expression that evaluates to a value which you then compare against your column value, ut it doesn't seem to make sense here either, not least because null handling is a little awkward.

You seem to want to replace that with simple Boolean logic:

```
where m_stat = :M_STAT   
and ((:M_ID = 0 and m_id is null)
  or (:M_ID ='a' and m_id is not null))
```

or to be consistent in treating the bind variable as a string:

```
where m_stat = :M_STAT   
and ((:M_ID = '0' and m_id is null)
  or (:M_ID ='a' and m_id is not null))
```

There is no 'else' to worry about; your `'do nothing'` string seems to be a placeholder that isn't intended to actually match against anything I.e. it's not a real `m_id` value you look for). If neither combined condition is true for a given row then the overall condition is false, and there won't be a match for that row and it will be filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is ambiguous but can be implemented as follows

```
select m_seqe
      ,m_emai
      ,m_phon
      ,e_seqe
      ,m_id
      ,
      ( case 
        when (:M_STAT = 0 )  and (m_id is not null ) then 'a'
        when (:M_STAT = 0 )  and (m_id is null  ) then 'b'
        when (:M_STAT = 200 ) then 'c'
        Else ' - ' end ) as Stat
from m_users 
where m_stat = :M_STAT and 
        (
            case when when (m_id IS NOT NULL AND :m_id = 'a') then 'a'
            when (m_id IS NULL AND :M_ID = 0 ) then 'b'
            when (m_id = 'do nothing') then 'c'
            when 'd' end 
        ) in ('a','b','c')
```